# How do I install the ES6 tmLanguage into TextMate 2?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I want to install the ES6 language syntax highlighting at https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage for TextMate 2. I cloned the repo, but it has a `.tmLanguage` directory with multiple files (`.tmTheme`, `.tmLanguage`, etc.).

Apparently, TM2 only supports everything inside a `.tmBundle`. Is there any clean way to just install the language support?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just ran into this as well. There's a (closed, unfortunately) [pull request](https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage/pull/122) that makes possible what you and I wanted. To get it working, I used dhensche's fork and performed the following:

1. Quit TextMate 2
2. Run the following:

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:dhensche/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage.git
   cd JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage
   ./create-bundle.sh
   cp -R JavaScriptNext.tmbundle ~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Pristine\ Copy/Bundles/
   ```
3. Re-launch TextMate 2, open an ES6 file, and select "JavaScript Next" from the toolbar along the bottom of the editor.

Hopefully Benvie will integrate proper TextMate 2 support in the build process soon, since it's not far off, as dhensche demonstrated.

Comment: That worked! Is there any way to get it to automatically recognize `.es6` extension files? (yes, I know, really should be `.js` but conflicts). And why does it not show up in the bundle editor?

Comment: Hmm, it shows up in the Bundle Editor for me, where I can edit file types.

Comment: You are right, it works. I just had to adjust the recognized files.

Comment: I received a bunch of errors `No such file or directory`. I had to `cp -R JavaScriptNext.tmbundle ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/` using 2.0-beta.7.4. Now TextMate recognizes files named babel.js and looks great. Thanks @CollinAllen.

Comment: You *should* be able to just doubleclick on the .tmBundle to import it into TextMate.

Comment: Upvoted but the pristine folder didn't exist for me. Just omitted that part of the path.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

The `JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage` became obsolete since the [official TextMate Javascript bundle](https://github.com/textmate/javascript.tmbundle) now supports the new ES features.

**Old answer below:**

---

To have the most up-to-date version you should create a new bundle in the Bundle Editor `File → New (⌘N)`, name it for convenience `JavaScript Next`:

[image]

Then, from the repo, open every `.tmLanguage`/`.tmPreferences`/`.tmTheme` file you want to use, and add it to your newly created bundle:

[image]

Now you should be able to select the `JavaScript Next` grammar:

[image]

Done!